# i am getting error Cannot read property 'getColumn' of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting error at 11th line and 13thline

how to solve the error

```
function sheetUpdate(props) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1cqhYHx-M54x-ZRmKLIdQo9DZ0jl-li-THy3w-wGf4UA');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Rent Info 7-25-22");
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A"); 
    var cell = range.createTextFinder("props.Unit ID").matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(true).findNext();
    console.log(cell)
    var range1 = sheet.getRange("1:1"); 
    var cell1 = range1.createTextFinder("props.field").matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(true).findNext();
    console.log(cell1)
    var colnum = cell1.getColumn();
      console.log(colnum)
    var rownum = cell.getRow();
      console.log(rownum)
    sheet.getRange(rownum,colnum).setValues(props.val)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is unclear what the keys in the `props` object are. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: it means `cell1` is returned as `null`. Use `Logger.log` if you working in GAS.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findNext()):

> **Return**
> `Range` — The next matching cell, or *null if there are no previous matches*.

You should check whether the search was successful, like this:

```js
    const cell = range.createTextFinder(props['Unit ID').matchEntireCell(true).matchCase(true).findNext();
    if (!cell) {
      console.log(`Could not find any cells with the value "${props['Unit ID'}".`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Found cell at ${cell.getA1Notation()}.`)
    }
```